# Cáracter de más se imprime al mostrar una palabra

Tags: c

Mi código es el siguiente código del juego del ahorcado en lenguaje C usando ficheros.

El error es el siguiente, se seleccionó cualquier dificultad, digamos fácil, la categoría es de animales, por ejemplo, se selecciona el animal BALLENA. Me tendría que imprimir en guiones bajos la palabra BALLENA "_ _ _ _ _ _ _" y adivinar la palabra, pero no sé por qué me imprime un guión bajo " _ " de más, por lo que no quiero eso.

Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

//PROTOTIPOS DE LAS FUNCIONES
void nivel_dificultad();
void ingreso_dificultad(int opcion_dificultad);
void empezarJuego(char palabras[100][1000], char nombre[]); 


//FUNCION PRINCIPAL MAIN
int main()
{
    nivel_dificultad();
    return 0;
} 

//FUNCION CATEGORIAS, IMPRIME EN PANTALLA LAS CATEGORIAS Y PERMITE ELEGIR UNA
void nivel_dificultad()
{
    system("cls");
    int opcion_dificultad;
    char nombre_usuario[10];
    printf("\n **************************************************************** \n");
    printf("\n\t\t Bienvenido al juego ahorcado \n");
    printf("\n **************************************************************** \n");
    printf("\n Ingrese su nombre de usuario: ");
    scanf("%s",&nombre_usuario);
    

    do
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\tJUEGO EL AHORCADO\n\n");
        printf(" NIVEL DE DIFICULTAD\n\n");
        printf(" 1. Facil\n");
        printf(" 2. Medio\n");
        printf(" 3. Dificil\n");
        printf(" Ingresa una opcion: ");
        scanf("%i",&opcion_dificultad);     
    }while(opcion_dificultad < 1 || opcion_dificultad > 4);
    
    //***************** Se crear un switch para ingresar a la opcion que elija el usuario *****************

    switch(opcion_dificultad)
    {
        case 1:
        ingreso_dificultad(opcion_dificultad);
        break;

        case 2: 
        ingreso_dificultad(opcion_dificultad);
        break;

        case 3: 
        ingreso_dificultad(opcion_dificultad);
        break;
    }
}


//******ESTA FUNCION RECIBE UN VALOR, Y DEPENDIENDO DEL VALOR RECIBIDO LLAMA A OTRA FUNCION PARA EMPEZAR EL JUEGO
//********  Las palabras ingresadas definen si solo se tienen que usar mayusculas o minusculas
void ingreso_dificultad (int opcion_dificultad)
{
    char nombrecat[3][15] = {"Facil","Medio","Dificil"};

    //***************** Se leen las palabras desde los archivos y se almacenan en arreglos ******************
    char facil[100][1000];
    char medio[100][1000];
    char dificil[100][1000];

    FILE *fp_animales = fopen("facil.txt","r");
    FILE *fp_frutas = fopen("medio.txt","r");
    FILE *fp_paises = fopen("dificil.txt","r");

    if(fp_animales == NULL || fp_frutas == NULL || fp_paises == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error al abrir el archivo, puede que no exista!");
    } 

    int linea = 0;
    while (!feof(fp_animales) && !feof(fp_frutas) && !feof(fp_paises))
    {
        fgets(facil[linea], 1000 , fp_animales);
        fgets(medio[linea], 1000 , fp_frutas);
        fgets(dificil[linea], 1000 , fp_paises);

        linea++;
    }

    fclose(fp_animales);
    fclose(fp_frutas);
    fclose(fp_paises);

    //****************** Termina la lectura de los archivos *********************************

    //************* Comienza el juego depende de la dificultad seleccionada *******************
    switch(opcion_dificultad){
        case 1:
            empezarJuego(facil,nombrecat[0]);
            break;
        case 2:
            empezarJuego(medio,nombrecat[1]);
            break;
        case 3:
            empezarJuego(dificil,nombrecat[2]);
            break;
    }   
}


//************ Funcion para comenzar el Juego ****************************
void empezarJuego (char palabras[100][1000], char nombre[])
{
    int opcion, longitud, espacios, puntos=1200;
    char letra;
    int aciertos = 0;
    int intentos = 0;
    int ganar = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    opcion = rand() % 10; //SE GENERA UN NUMERO ALEATORIO COMPRENDIDO ENTRE 0 Y 9 para elegir una de las palabras para adivinar
    longitud = strlen(palabras[opcion]); //SE ALMACENA LA LONGITUD DE LA PALABRA 
    char frase[longitud]; // Guarda la longitud de la palabra seleccionada
    
    //******************SE COLOCAN GUIONES BAJOS EN EL ARRAY DE CARACTERES FRASE ******************

    for(int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
    {
        frase[i] = '_'; 
    }
    
    do{
        aciertos = 0;
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\tJUEGO EL AHORCADO\n\n");
        printf(" CATEGORIA: %s\n\n",nombre);
        printf(" Intentos Disponibles: %i\t\t\t\tPuntuacion: %i\n\n",6-intentos,puntos);
        
        //IMPRIME EL ARRAY DE CARACTERES FRASE
        printf("\n\n\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
        {
            printf(" %c ",frase[i]);
        }

        
        if (intentos == 6){
            printf("\n\n PERDISTE!!\n");
            printf(" LA SOLUCION ERA: %s\n\n",palabras[opcion]);
            printf(" Presiona una tecla volver al menu......");
            getch();
            main(); 
        }
        
        
        //***************** PROCESO QUE COMPRUEBA SI SE HA ADIVINADO LA PALABRA
        espacios=0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
        {
            if (frase[i] == '_')
            {
                espacios++;
            }
        }
        
        
        if (espacios == 0)
        {
            printf("\n\n FELICIDADES.. GANASTE!!\n\n");
            printf(" Presiona una tecla para volver a jugar..");
            getch();
            //categorias();     
        }
        
        
        printf("\n\n Digite una letra: ");
        scanf(" %c",&letra);
        
        //PROCESO QUE VERIFICA SI LA LETRA INGRESADA EXISTE EN LA PALABRA, SI ESTO ES VERDADERO, SE REEMPLAZA EL CARACTER GUION BAJO POR LA LETRA INGRESADA 
        for (int j = 0; j < longitud; j++)
        {
            if (letra == palabras[opcion][j])
            {
                frase[j] = letra;
                aciertos++;
            }   
        }
        
        if (aciertos == 0){
            intentos++; 
            puntos -= 200;
        }
        
        
            
    }while(intentos != 7);  
}
```

Ya he estado unas horas buscando el error, pero no lo encuentro y no quiero dejar pasar por alto ese detalle, aunque es pequeño no me gusta.

Answer (score 1):

El problema viene de que al leer las palabras desde un archivo mediante `fgets()` estás leyendo también los retornos de carro que hay al final de cada palabra.

Por tanto si lees una línea que contenía "BALLENA", en tu array queda almacenada la cadena `"BALLENA\n"` siendo `\n` el retorno de carro. Cuando más adelante calculas la longitud de la palabra para imprimir los guiones, te sale 1 más (pues de hecho hay un carácter más, el \n).

Puedes eliminar los caracteres de fin de línea poniendo un terminador (byte de valor 0) en la posición en que aparezca el \n, con el truco siguiente:

```
        fgets(facil[linea], 1000 , fp_animales);
        facil[linea][strcspn(facil[linea], "\n")] = 0;
        // Y así con los restantes fgets()
```

Si tu sistema utiliza \r\n para marcar los finales de línea, cambia en el código anterior el `"\n"` por `"\r\n"`.